# Disable routing on an interface in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wireless-networking

I'm working at Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS. This system contains a interface eno1 (Interface Ethernet) and interface wlan0 (Wireless).

I need to DISABLE the routing through the wireless interface...
I need the routing to be performed only by the eno1 interface.

The eno1 is using fixed IP and wlan0 uses DHCP.

**Obs:** The two network interfaces wlan0 and eth0 are in same network (10.xx.xx.xx/8).

Thanks for help!

Comment: On my Ubuntu 22.04 machine, top menu bar, Network:  I can turn the interface OFF.  Does that work for you?

Comment: I'm using a CLI in Ubuntu... I need to leave the wireless interface active, but I don't want it to be the default routing interface.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to clarify what you want to achieve. You want to disable ip-forwarding or you want to set a default route, or don't want a default route set via DHCP?

Comment: Hi xenoson

I need the wireless interface NOT to do routing, just the eth0 interface.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify **HOW** `eno1` or `wlan0` gets configured, but you could give this a shot anyway, assuming that you're using the Ubuntu default DHCP client and ...

Edit your `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` to look something like this (you will obviously want to make adjustments as needed, read `man dhclient.conf` for details):

```
interface "wlan0" {
    send dhcp-lease-time 3600;
    request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset,
         domain-name, domain-name-servers, host-name;
    require subnet-mask, domain-name-servers;
    script "/sbin/dhclient-script";
}
```

The crucial part is to override the defaults for `request`, omitting the `routers` .... that should give you no routing over that interface.

Comment: Did the above make any sense to you?  [@Bruno_S](https://superuser.com/users/1808576/bruno-s)